# Typeset Like Jackson's E&M

Tags: math-mode, equations, books

I was wondering if there's a package or style to match that of [Classical Electrodynamics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047130932X) by J.D. Jackson (there is a multiple pages preview). His integrals are almost vertical and everything related to E&M just looks proper in his style.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you sample a page or somehow describe what you mean? Otherwise we can't do much.

Comment: I am not sure whether we can include here a small image under Fair use. At Amazon there is a free preview showing the typesetting of equations: [Jackson on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Electrodynamics-Third-David-Jackson/dp/047130932X). It does not look too special to me; vectors are bold and the typeface needs to be identified to emulate the layout.

Comment: Have you tried writing Prof Jackson and asking him if he has a LaTeX style, or at least knows the fonts?

Comment: the typeface looks like times,

Comment: @barbarabeeton Spot on. On the colophon it says Times 10 on 12.

Comment: I found a one I like! http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~alexey/emulateapj/apjfonts.sty